# How to consume Google In-App purchases Server-side

Tags: java, android

I need to be able to **consume** a purchase without an Android client being connected using a backend server. Is this possible? If not, why? I am trying to make it possible to process a purchase entirely without a user being connected in the case of a disconnection.

Do I need to send a message to my client from my server requesting consumption and then provide a response to the server when the purchase is consumed? **This is what I am trying to avoid.**

I see various other similar questions but they are for the AIDL API which is now discontinued for google-in-app billing.

Relative API(s);

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-androidpublisher/v3-rev103-1.25.0

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION:** To my knowledge, at this current time, July 2019, it is **not** possible to consume a purchase from a server. It is only possible from the android client.

This means that the flow of the purchase depends on a request to a client and an response from the client, followed by a required [GET](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get) to validate the purchase has actually been consumed.